What is the most efficient algorithm for computing $E[x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n]$ in a multivariate normal distribution?
I am working with a multivariate normal distribution $\mathbf{x} = [x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n] \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$, and I need to compute the expectation $E[x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n]$ efficiently for arbitrary $n$.
What I Know:

For small $n$, I can use Wick's theorem (or Isserlis' theorem), which decomposes the moment into sums of products of covariances $\Sigma_{ij}$ and means $\mu_i$.
This approach, however, requires enumerating all pairings, which becomes computationally expensive as $n$ increases ($O(n!)$ in the worst case).
Monte Carlo methods are an option, but they introduce statistical error, and I would prefer an exact algorithm if one exists.

My Question:

Is there a known efficient algorithm (or approximation technique) to compute $E[x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n]$ in a multivariate normal distribution?
Specifically:

Are there matrix-based methods that avoid explicitly enumerating pairings?
Are there dynamic programming approaches or graph-based techniques that scale better for large $n$?
Any references to academic papers, algorithms, or implementations would be highly appreciated.



Context:
In my application, $n$ can range from small (e.g., $n = 4$) to large (e.g., $n > 50$). Computational efficiency is critical, especially for larger $n$.
Thank you for your insights!

crossposted https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5015799/87355 (two days ago, the typical recommendation is to wait a week)

You are asking for an algorithm to compute a Hafnian of a symmetric matrix. According to Wikipedia, this problem is #P-complete.
A reference for an algorithm, with runtime $O(n^3 2^{n/2})$ is "A faster hafnian formula for complex matrices
and its benchmarking on a supercomputer",
A. Björklund, B. Gupt, N. Quesada (arXiv)

Q: Are there matrix-based methods that avoid explicitly enumerating pairings?
You could use the generating function,
$$M(t_1,t_2,\ldots t_n)=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\sum_{i}t_i x_i}\right] = \exp\left({\sum_{i}t_i\mu_i + \tfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j}t_i \Sigma_{ij} t_j}\right),$$
to obtain moments
$$\mathbb{E}[x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n]=\lim_{t_1,t_2,\ldots t_n\rightarrow 0}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial t_i}\right)M(t_1,t_2,\ldots t_n).$$

Why is there a limit in your formula? As far as I understand the function to differentiate is C^inf, so one can just take the derivatives in 0.

Also, this is a formula, but turning it into an algorithm is not straightforward. How does one compute that mixed derivative? Multiple nested automated differentiation? Finite differences?
